# How can I solve this Exception in Tkinter callback Error?

Tags: python, tkinter, text-to-speech, google-translation-api

Name of the project: Text to Speech Convertor(Multi-Lang)
Library Using: Tkinter, googletrans,Combobox

May I know how can I solve this issue? It would be really helpful if anyone replies as soon as possible..

**Error:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\indib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\indib\Desktop\Text to Speech\translator.py", line 17, in data
    textget=change(text=masg,src=s,dest=d)
  File "C:\Users\indib\Desktop\Text to Speech\translator.py", line 10, in change
    trans1=trans.translate(text,src=src1,dest=dest1)
  File "C:\Users\indib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\indib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "C:\Users\indib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\indib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

This is the code of my project till now. The code is working fine as I have compiled while I was doing step by step but during full execution I am getting this error. Getting this error when I am pressing Translate button...

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from googletrans import Translator,LANGUAGES

def change(text="type",src="English",dest="Hindi"):
    text1=text
    src1=src
    dest1=dest
    trans=Translator()
    trans1=trans.translate(text,src=src1,dest=dest1)
    return trans1.text

def data():
    s=comb_sor.get()
    d=comb_dest.get()
    masg=Sor_txt.get(1.0,END)
    textget=change(text=masg,src=s,dest=d)
    dest_txt.delete(1.0,END)
    dest_txt.insert(END,textget)

root = Tk()
root.title("Translator")
root.geometry("500x700")
root.config(bg='Red')

lab_txt=Label(root,text="Translator",font=("Time New Roman",40,"bold"))
lab_txt.place(x=100,y=40,height=50,width=300)

frame=Frame(root).pack(side=BOTTOM)

lab_txt=Label(root,text="Source Text",font=("Time New Roman",20,"bold"),fg="Black",bg="red")
lab_txt.place(x=100,y=100,height=20,width=300)

Sor_txt=Text(frame,font=("Time New Roman",20,"bold"),wrap=WORD)
Sor_txt.place(x=10,y=130,height=150,width=480)

list_text=list(LANGUAGES.values())

comb_sor=ttk.Combobox(frame,value=list_text)
comb_sor.place(x=10,y=300,height=40,width=150)
comb_sor.set("english")

button_change=Button(frame,text="Translate",relief=RAISED,command=data)
button_change.place(x=170,y=300,height=40,width=150)

comb_dest=ttk.Combobox(frame,value=list_text)
comb_dest.place(x=330,y=300,height=40,width=150)
comb_dest.set("english")

lab_txt=Label(root,text="Dest Text",font=("Time New Roman",20,"bold"),fg="Black",bg="red")
lab_txt.place(x=100,y=360,height=20,width=300)

dest_txt=Text(frame,font=("Time New Roman",20,"bold"),wrap=WORD)
dest_txt.place(x=10,y=400,height=150,width=480)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you done something like put `print(f'{text=}, {src1=}, {dest1=}')` before `trans1=trans.translate(text,src=src1,dest=dest1)` to see what's being passed in?

Comment: Also [this](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/280) might be related.

Comment: @Axe319 I tried putting that print statement and while executing the values which i am giving are passing but again that issue is coming..

This is the output of that statement: text='hi\n', src1='english', dest1='hindi'

Comment: The error is GOING to occur. The `print` statement is to help you trouble shoot. This line `trans1=trans.translate(text,src=src1,dest=dest1)` is throwing an error. That being said, if you install the alpha version that my link suggested with `python -m pip install --upgrade googletrans==3.1.0a0`, it should fix the problem.